# How do I check if an answer is in a 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
blueprint = [[1,"A"], [2,"C"], [3,"B"], [4,"D"], [5,"A"], [6,"A"], [7,"B"], [8,"A"], [9,"C"], [10,"A"], [11,"D"], [12,"A"], [13,"C"], [14,"C"]
         ,[15,"B"], [16,"A"], [17,"B"], [18,"A"], [19,"C"], [20,"D"]]


def check_answer(students_answer):
    points = 0
    total = 20
    if students_answer[0]==blueprint[0][1]:
        points =+ 1
    elif students_answer[1]==blueprint[1][1]:
        points =+ 1
#etc.

    else:
        points =+ 0
    score = (points*100)/(total)
    return score

print(check_answer(["A", "C"]))
```

Why doesn't my function calculate the % of right answers for longer than answer 1, which is "A"?

Comment: most likely because you are using `elif`. So when the first `if` branch is executed it won't go down further and check the `elif`s. I recommend you use a loop for this type of thing.

Comment: looks like you need a loop. You're not going to copy/paste the conditions like this if there are 1000 answers.

Comment: Ok, I actually switched from if to elif, because the if didn't work either :/ . But I am new to 2D lists, so I don't have a clue to how to setup a loop for it? Got any links? Sorry for the stupid questions here

Comment: Thank you very much! And I know it's a stonecutter approach to this, but I am totally new to coding, so sorry for the stupid mistakes and everything

Answer (score 1):

I don't get why you need to recall the list index in `blueprint` but if the data are like this, you could just `zip` the data together, unpack, and compare.

This way of doing it is really unefficient. What if you have 100 questions? will you copy/paste 100 times your (wrong) `elif` statements?

Score 1 for success, 0 for fail, divide by total and multiply by 100, in a generator comprehension fed to `sum`:

```
def check_answer(students_answer):
    return 100*(sum(correct==attempt for (_,correct),attempt in zip(blueprint,students_answer))/len(blueprint))
```

Answer (score 1):

The first items in the tuples in your `blueprint` list are redundant because they are simply the indices of their respective tuples plus one. You should make it a simple list of strings instead:

```
blueprint = ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D']
```

so that you can calculate the percentage of right answers in `student_answer` with a zip of the two lists like this:

```
sum(1 for s, b in zip(student_answer, blueprint) if s == b) / len(student_answer) * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't my function calculate the % of right answers for longer than answer 1, which is "A"?

Let's take a look at your data & function

```
# data
blueprint = [[1,"A"], [2,"C"], [3,"B"], [4,"D"], [5,"A"], [6,"A"], [7,"B"], [8,"A"], [9,"C"], [10,"A"], [11,"D"], [12,"A"], [13,"C"], [14,"C"], [15,"B"], [16,"A"], [17,"B"], [18,"A"], [19,"C"], [20,"D"]]

# function call
print(check_answer(["A", "C"]))
```

first list in `blueprint` is `[1,"A"]`. the `check_answer()` argument is `["A", "C"]`. When the line in the  loop here runs, it found what it's looking for

```
if students_answer[0]==blueprint[0][1]:    # students_answer[0] is "A", blueprint[0][1] is "A", too
    points =+ 1
elif students_answer[1]==blueprint[1][1]:
    points =+ 1
#etc.
```

that means it skips all the elifs & else, straight to calculating `score`. That's why score only contains the first `"A"`.

one approach you can do is to use `zip(*blueprint)` to unpack the lists inside blueprint, into this

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20),
('A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'D')]
```

then loop on that to count the grades.

so,

```
scorelist = list(zip(*blueprint))
total = len(scorelist[1])
answer_list = ["A", "C"]
first_a, second_a = answer_list
points = 0

for sc in scorelist[1]:
    if sc == first_a or sc == second_a:
        points += 1

score = (points*100)/(total)
print(score)
```

or you can even just joined all the scores strings & use `str.count()`

```
joined_scores = ''.join(scorelist[1])
print(joined_scores)
# 'ACBDAABACADACCBABACD'

points = joined_scores.count(first_a) + joined_scores.count(second_a)
print(points*100/total)
# 65.0
```